# how to set expiry to form data in java?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to do timer operation on After submitting a form if data has been approved within 6 hrs then only it will be updated in database otherwise delete the record. How do I do it?

Comment: We're not here to do your homework. Post some progress first please.

Comment: When the form has been submitted, first you update it into DB with the status is pending(?), after that, a process will automatically run, collect all pending record and check if it passes 6 hours then delete it? That's what comes up in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add a column about submitting time. Before someone approve submit, you can verification time column is not expired. In addition， you can add a column to describe which row is approved.

Answer (score 0):

I would store a timestamp with each record, and write the code to purge all the records older than six ours. I would run that code regularily (say every 15 minutes). At the record creation, I could also schedule a task for 6 hours later that would run the code.

Comment: and how do i do that schedule code? It will be on server so how do I put a timer on that?

Comment: @DaminiNarkhede with an ExecutorService?